# Storing abstract and concrete types in Map

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have an interface and class like following:

```
public interface Message extends Wrappable
{
}

public class MessageImpl implements Message
{
}
```

I want to use Java generics to store these Classes into a Map with interface as key and impl as value as:

```
map.put(Message.class, MessageImpl.class);
```

I want it to be typesafe, where key must extends Wrappable and value must extend key class.
Any help on this?

Comment: You can't use Java generics in the code you've provided because the types are not generic types.  Maybe what you are really wanting is a type-safe heterogenous container?  Also, it is often not possible to use generic types as keys for maps because in Java, generic types are not reified.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with such a map? An interface can be implemented by multiple classes, so shouldn't the Impl be the key and the interface the value, instead?

Comment: I have one jar for the interfaces and the jar with impl will be provided it the runtime and that specific implementation should be used. But each implementation class may not have this implementation definition in the same package, like x.y.Message for jpa jar this entity might be in x.y.jpa.MessageImpl class while cassandra jar may have this in x.y.cassandra.MessageImpl. Then my services only have interfaces jar at compile time so all coding is done on that but i need to have some way to find the correct impl class in order to instantiate Message.

Comment: Message message = new x.y.?.MessageImpl(); I hope my problem is more clear now

Answer (score 4):

A basic `Map` can't do this type safely, but you can create a simple wrapper around a `Map` to enforce type safety.  That might look something like

```
class MyMap {
  private final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
  public <A extends Wrappable, B extends A> void put(
      Class<A> interfaceClass, Class<B> implClass) {
    // you can't statically enforce that A is an interface 
    // and B is a concrete class, though you can do it at runtime
    assert interfaceClass.isInterface();
    assert !Modifier.isAbstract(implClass.getModifiers());
    map.put(interfaceClass, implClass);
  }

  public <A extends Wrappable> Class<? extends A> get(Class<A> interfaceClass) {
    return (Class<? extends A>) map.get(interfaceClass);
  }
}
```

Comment: `return interfaceClass.asSubclass(map.get(interfaceClass));` doesn't compile. What's wrong with just `return (Class<? extends A>) map.get(interfaceClass);`?

Comment: Ah, I see it, you're right.  I was hoping to dynamically enforce that that cast worked.

Comment: I need to iterate over all the Entries of the map, but I guess that should be easy to do now. Thanks Louis